# Why does minifyEnabled show most of my code?

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, minify, android-proguard

I have this class in my ProGuard.

```
-keep,allowshrinking class com.MyClass {
    public <methods>;
    protected <methods>;
    public static <methods>;
    public <init>(...);
}
```

When I look at the AAR it shows like this:

```
public class MyClass implements a {
    private static final MyClass a = new MyClass();
    private a b = new b();

    private MyClass() {
    }

    public static MyClass getInstance() {
        return a;
    }

    public void doSomething(int var1, int var2) {
        this.b.doSomething(var1, var2);
    }
}
```

If I go to `private a b = new b();` and do `Crtl + b` I am able to read the code of class `b`. Shouldn't that code be obfuscated? How do I force it to be obfuscated?

This is what shows inside class `b`, that should be obfuscated.

```
class b implements a {
    b() {
    }

    public void doSomething(int var1, int var2) {
        int var3 = var1 + var2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can it be that `android:debuggable="true"` is set in your manifest file?

Comment: what were you expecting? As far as I know, the class code is still accessible using proguard. What is does is the renaming of all variables/class/methods, and remove debug data, so people can't debug your code. Still, the code is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obfuscation capabilities of ProGuard are limited to renaming of class / method / field names. If you need more sophisticated obfuscation (obfuscation of actual code / instructions) you should take a look at [DexGuard](http://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard), the commercial variant of ProGuard.